# Tensorflow: replace an operation with an other

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a graph that looks like that:

```
 I  W
 \ /
  E
  |
X1...Xn
```

And I'd like to replace the operation E to have a new graph like that:

```
 I  Q
 \ /
  L
  |
X1...Xn
```

But I'm getting lost with the graph_editor interface.
I've tried doing: `ge.graph_replace(E, {E: L})`, but I get: `ValueError: Targets and replacements are not connected!`.

EDIT: The code looks like that

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FLAGS.load_model + ".meta")
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    codebooks, labels = read_qnpy(FLAGS.output_qnpy)
    with tf.variable_scope('Output_qnpy'):
        embeddings = qembs_graph(codebooks, labels) 
        all_ids = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Model/Output/nce_loss/concat:0')
        el = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Model/Output/nce_loss/embedding_lookup:0')
        word_lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, all_ids, name="word_lookup")
        ge.graph_replace(el, {el: word_lookup})
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see your attempt and what's wrong with it?

Comment: I've just added the code.